# Footer error when using bootstraps cover template

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

When using bootstraps cover template:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/cover/#

If I resize the window to a small level to allow scrolling or simply include enough text to warrant scrolling the footer goes a solid colour (see linked picture). It even does this on the template but I'd love to fix it

Can anyone help with this would really really appreciate it
[The gradient seems to stop and simply go one solid cov=lour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlXIV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body{
     height: auto !important;
 }
.cover-container{
     min-height: 100vh
}
```